# Type-mixed integer division in C: compiler bug or defined behaviour?

Tags: c, twos-complement

I've encountered a quirk when writing software for a small ARM processor compiled using GCC.  The processor has no hardware division engine, so division is implemented in software.

The following code replicates the behaviour, volatile statements are used to avoid optimisation:

```
volatile int32_t x = -4000;
volatile uint32_t y = 4;
volatile int32_t z = x / y;

uart_printf(DBG_LVL_INFO, "%d / %d = %d\r\n", x, y, z);
```

The result printed for z is `1073740824`,  but I would expect a result of `-1000`.

The type mixing appears to be critical.  Replacing the `uint32_t` with `int32_t` resolves the bug.

`-1000` interpreted incorrectly as an unsigned integer would not produce the result, which, interestingly appears to be equal to the result plus 2<sup>30</sup>.

Is this a bug, or just defined behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing math operations on C, *narrower* type will be converted to *wider* one. In your case, all `int32_t` variables are converted to `uint32_t`, this is due **promotion** effect.

`-4000` is a very big number in `uint32_t`. In fact, it is `0xFFFFFFFF - 4000` which is around 4 billion. If you divide 4 billion (and something) by 4, you get result you have.

Solve your problem by using either same types everywhere or do casting before variable is used:

```
volatile int32_t z = x / (int32_t)y;
```

When printing your result, `%d` by using `int32_t` or `uint32_t` is undefined behavior, because it only works with `int` type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense.

Comment: re: printf, I believe the compiler treats all varadic integer types as being cast to int type, so using uint32_t and friends *should* work. I stand to be corrected, however.

Comment: @TomOldbury you believe wrong. Long is also varuadic int but you have to use %l for it.